# Fixing Font Normalization

Tags: terminal, fonts

I'm using a font in Alacritty that does not display the umlaut in some files/filenames correctly.

To reproduce:

```
$ echo FAIL $'A\u0308'
FAIL Ä
$ echo OK $'\u00c4'
OK Ä
```

which is displayed like this:

[image: umlaut]

According to the author of Alacritty it doesn't do normalization and the fonts do not position the symbols correctly.

Is there a tool that can fix this font so it will display the `Ä` correctly in both versions like it is displayed in the browser?

The font in question is Consolas though it happens with similar fonts like Inconsolata or Noto Sans Mono. It works mostly in Fira Mono.